# Linked List adding elements at certain points

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a LinkedList, the problem I'm having is adding elements to this list, I've already added elements in the main class and want to know how to add elements at the beginning of the list and at the end of the list. The current is able to print, but when i add new elements they cant be seen. I also want to know about getting the size of the linked list.

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

}

public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    int size;


    public void AddBeginning(int data) {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            newNode.next = head;
            this.size++;        
            head = newNode;

    }

    public void addAtEnd(int data) {
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);  
    } 

    public void getSize() {
        System.out.println(size);
    }

    public void printList(Node head) {
        Node current = head;
        while (current !=null) {
        System.out.print(current.data + "-->");
        current = current.next;
        }       
        System.out.print(current);
    }

}


public class Tester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();


        Node head = new Node(25);

        Node second = new Node(22);

        Node third = new Node(7);

        head.next = second;
        second.next = third;

        ll.AddBeginning(20);

        ll.printList(head);




    }

    }
```

I would like to add 20 at the beginning and another integer at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to Node 20 `ll.AddBeginning(20);` to `LinkedList.head` And Trying to print the list using `Tester.head (declared in main method)`

Solution:
Step 1 : Initialize LinkedList.head either

```
     - Using constructor or
             LinkedList ll = new LinkedList(head);

             public LinkedList(Node head) {
                 this.head = head;
             }

     - Assign head to LinkedList object i.e., ll
              ll.head = head; // Need to initialize Linked List with Head
```

Step 2 : No need to pass head variable to printList() function. It prints the LinkedList.head elements

```
         ll.printList(); //Here you passing Tester.head not required
```

Code :

**Tester main method**

```
    ll.head = head; // Need to initialize Linked List with Head

    ll.AddBeginning(20); //Here actually adding node to linkedList head

    ll.printList(); //Here you passing Tester.head not required
```

**LinkedList.PrintList method**

```
public void printList() {
    Node current = this.head;//changed to linkedlist.head
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.print(current.data + "-->");
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.print(current);
}
```